# How do I split a string in ruby maintaining whitespaces in the split

Tags: ruby

I have a string:

```
"hello\t    World\nbla"
```

I would like to split it to:

```
["hello\t    ",
"World\n", 
"bla"]
```

How would I do this in Ruby?

Comment: BTW Sam, your profile almost has 1337 views hehe. Hello to a fellow Sydney-sider.

Comment: Hello to you as well. I should get around to attending the monthly roro meetups

Comment: Yea definitely. I think there's one coming up on Tuesday August 11. And there's Railscamp in November too.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
>> "hello\t    World\nbla".scan /\S+\s*/
=> ["hello\t    ", "World\n", "bla"]
```

Answer (score 2):

Hopefully this helps..

```
>> "hello\t   World\nbla".scan(/\w+\s*/)
=> ["hello\t   ", "World\n", "bla"]
```

Comment: Much prettier than my hackyiness :p

Comment: \w will be a bit funny about hyphenated words, for example